# Error while converting javascript code to jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have following code where openNav function is called.

```
<div id="main">
        <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
        <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right.</p>
        <span id="sp1" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">☰ open</span>
    </div>
```

i have Javascript code which works fine

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}
```

i tried to convert it in jquery but it shows error openNav is not defined.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#sp1').click(function openNav() {
        $('#mySidenav').style.width = "250px";
        $('#main').style.marginLeft = "250px";
    })
</script>
```

It compiles and run properly but when i click on `open (onclick event)` it throws an exception that openNav is undefined.

Please explain what is the problem ? 
thanks

Comment: I think instead of using jquery you should use this function.     'var text;function $(text){return(document.querySelector(text));}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pure jQuery** - You need to use the `css` method

```
    $('#mySidenav').css( "width", "250px" );
    $('#main').css( "margin-Left", "250px");
```

**Your approach** - Or simply access the DOM element from jquery object using `[0]` index

```
   $('#mySidenav')[0].style.width = "250px";
    $('#main')[0].style.marginLeft = "250px";
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked.
Can you tell me converting it into JQuery is good or not ? according to me javascript doesn't work fine in all browser while JQuery don't have that problem and many other advantages.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <html>
            <head>
            <title>Sample Page</title>
            </head>

        <body>
             <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <div id="main">
                <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
                <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right.</p>
                <span id="sp1" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">☰ open</span>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function openNav() {
                 $('#mySidenav').css( "width", "250px" );
                 $('#main').css( "margin-Left", "250px");
               }
        </script>
        </body>

        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#sp1').click(function openNav() {
        $('#mySidenav').style.width = "250px";
        $('#main').style.marginLeft = "250px";
    })
</script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#sp1').click(function(){
        $('#mySidenav').css({"width":"250px"});
        $('#main').css({"magin-left":"250px"});
    })
</script>
```

And remove the `onclick` attribute from your html its obsolete in this approach

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `opennav`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#sp1').click(function() {
        $('#mySidenav').css('width', "250px");
        $('#main').css('marginLeft', "250px");
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery, remove on click function from html:

```
<div id="main">
        <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
        <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right.</p>
        <span id="sp1" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer">☰ open</span>
    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#sp1').click(function() {
        $('#mySidenav').css('width','250px'); 
        $('#main').css('margin-left','250px');
 });
</script>
```

Comment: If i remove click event how it will call function.
What i am doing here is when i click on `open` it will open an navigation sidebar menu. and removing click event won't do that. That's what i believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you use  `$('#sp1').click(function openNav() { ..})` you may see an error openNav is not defined

```
function openNav() {
         $('#mySidenav').css( "width", "250px" );
    $('#main').css( "margin-Left", "250px");
    }
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9sh6w5r6/)